# Symfony Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\app\cache\prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__MediaBundleEntityMedia.php'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

when i enter any type of entry this type of error show up and admin panel not working any more but when i delete the entrys from myphpadmin every things go normal

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\app\cache\prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__MediaBundleEntityMedia.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 209
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\app\cache\prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__MediaBundleEntityMedia.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 209

config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

#framework:
#    validation:
#        cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apc
#    serializer:
#        cache: serializer.mapping.cache.apc

#doctrine:
 #   orm:
  #      metadata_cache_driver: apc
   #     result_cache_driver: apc
    #    query_cache_driver: apc

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

confing.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
- { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

## Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed

## http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration

parameters:
    locale: en
    files_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public_html/uploads/'
    files_directory_mp3: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public_html/files/'
    files_directory_read: '/uploads/'
    files_directory_read_mp3: '/files/'
    token_app: "8cve98hty47h2uf0dfg4re7fg0wdhn24ffr3er3reg67yu20"
    fire_base_key: AIzaSyCWwALLUkDm_ya6EstPhP3ft-tSCPcCfeU
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: [en] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig','php']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

## Twig Configuration

twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

## Doctrine Configuration

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
        string_functions:
            SHA1: AppBundle\DQL\Sha1
```

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User

## Swiftmailer Configuration

swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
ivory_ck_editor:
    configs:
        user_config:
            language: 'en'
            width:  '100%'
            height: '400px'
            filebrowserBrowseRoute:           "media_index"
            filebrowserBrowseRouteAbsolute:   true 
            toolbar: [['Undo','Redo'],[ 'Cut','Copy','Paste'],["Bold","Italic","Underline","TextColor"],['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],['NumberedList', 'BulletedList',"Checkbox"],["BidiLtr","BidiRtl"]]
            uiColor: "#ffffff"
            removePlugins: 'elementspath' 
        step_config:
            language: 'en'
            width:  '100%'
            height: '200px'
            filebrowserBrowseRoute:           "media_index"
            filebrowserBrowseRouteAbsolute:   true 
            toolbar: [['Undo','Redo'],[ 'Cut','Copy','Paste'],["Bold","Italic","Underline","TextColor"],['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],['NumberedList', 'BulletedList',"Checkbox"],["BidiLtr","BidiRtl"]]
            uiColor: "#ffffff"
            removePlugins: 'elementspath' 
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root:  %kernel.root_dir%/../public_html/
                cache_prefix:  uploads/cache
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root:  %kernel.root_dir%/../public_html/
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        image_thumb:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [300, 300], mode: outbound }
        image_image:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [1024, 720], mode: outbound }
        album_thumb:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [450, 450], mode: outbound }
        image_thumb_api:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [400, 260], mode: outbound }
        image:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [50000, 50000], mode: outbound }

```
    video_thumb_api:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [400, 200], mode: outbound }           

    category_thumb:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [200, 200], mode: outbound }
    category_thumb_api:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
    language_thumb:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [200, 200], mode: outbound }
    language_thumb_api:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
    application_thumb_icon:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
    application_thumb_cover:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [400, 260], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: Have you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because, this seems to me to be simple case of rights of the Entity Proxy folder being incorrectly set. Please remember that folder rights in projects are committed in to git history. If it's something else you need to clarify this more in your question, mainly by removing a lot of unrelated stuff and fixing formatting.

Comment: set read/write permission to "var/" folder